# Manage multiple models in multiple controllers to keep track on them

Tags: java, javafx, static, singleton, fxml

I was trying to make a simple application in javafx.

I had 8 views (`FXML`), so one model for each and same for the controllers.

I had to keep the "context" for each model wherever I was... So I had a function `setContext` which would take a parameter which is a class that regroup every models.

So in every controllers, I had every models.

But a bit latter, I had to had another page, which would take the result of all those page (questionnaire) and show it, so I could have multiple questionnaire... So I was facing the exact same problem, but I didn't want to do it all over again... Because as soon as I'm creating a new questionnaire, I lose the context of the previous one. I also had to add `abstractModel` and `abstractController` for stocking every models. It was ratchet.

So I gave up the idea of one controller for each view.

I ended up with a functionnal application, but with one controller which as over 1000 lines... it's only a questionnaire.

I was wondering if there were any possibilities to do what I attempt to do, with multiple controller, but where I don't need to set the "context"? Like... the pages/views auto-save somehow and won't re-instantiate if I'm not asking for it (like a new questionnaire would reset).

Sush as a static class, like a `singleton`, but for views and which I'm able to instantiate for every questionnaire. But then again, I keep a track on the old ones.

I'm pretty sure it's possible, but can't find anything about it maybe my formulation of the question is just wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx to get some ideas. There the different views communicate via a Service class singleton

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll see what I can do with that

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your exact situation and problem is. Can you provide a short example of what you currently have, and explain what the problem with it is?

Comment: Probably you should define the question data in a way that allows you to represent all the questionaires using the same data structure. Having one fxml per questionaire seems like a unhealthy amount of coupling between model and controller/view.

Comment: @sillyfly I don't have anything actually... I erased it all! I'm just wondering if I could keep the same instance of my model whatever the controller I'm in... Instead of setting my "new" model in every controller, I would keep the same, like a singleton. I'm talking about models, but it would be the view that is save as well

Comment: @fabian Yes actually I do have the same data structure. It's just that I can generate multiple questionnaires, which all have the same models and same views and same controllers. But when I create one, it instantiate everything, but it keeps track on all of them so I can edit them later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is bit abstract and it is hard to give a definitive answer.  But you *might* benefit from introducing a [dependency injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) framework.

One way to do that would be to use [Gluon Ignite](http://gluonhq.com/announcing-gluon-ignite-easy-javafx-dependency-injection/): "With this library, developers can use popular dependency injection frameworks in their JavaFX applications, including inside their FXML controllers.".  You can choose a dependency injection framework you wish from those supported (for example, Dagger, Guice or Spring).  With those systems, you can apply scoping rules to your model classes such as [Singleton](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes), for those models for which you only wish to have a single instance for your application.  You can also use other scoping rules and producers to create models that have different scopes such as within the context of a wizard or created new every time a form is shown, etc.

Beware that using dependency injection frameworks might make your application a little bit more difficult to understand. Anybody maintaining your application has to additionally learn the dependency injection framework.  The framework will create objects and inject references to them into your code automatically and your application might be a bit more difficult to debug due to some seemingly magical generated operations that you don't control.  Still, it's a tradeoff and, for medium sized applications, the gain in using dependency injection is probably worth it for a lot of apps.  From the description you provided, your application may fall into this class, so you should probably seriously consider this approach.

Note that an alternate to a dependency injection system is a service locator (read about it in the Martin Fowler article on dependency injection that I linked earlier).  A sample (extremely basic) version of a service locator would be the vista navigator in this small [JavaFX navigation framework](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6460130), though that doesn't pretend to be a full MVC system.

> It's just that I can generate multiple questionnaires, which all have the same models and same views and same controllers. But when I create one, it instantiate everything, but it keeps track on all of them so I can edit them later

You could replace your in-memory structure for keeping track of stuff for editing with a persistent storage, for example a JPA based DB access layer or a NoSQL based DB access layer.  One advantage of this could also be that the state of the application would be saved if the application is shut down, then restarted, so the user could just pick up where they left off in their questionnaire.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this information! I know the question is a bit abstract, I'm not sure how I can formulate my question and plus, it's a bit harder to express myself in english! I think the best solution would be to actually store the data for each questionnaire I create. Somebody mentionned the word "HSQL", I've still not look what this is, but I may try with NoSQL as well! I may try to use dependency injection combine with a DB actually.. thanks again!